# On asp.net-mvc site, why isn't html DropdownlistFor() working properly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selected, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlistitem

I am having an issue where the item in the dropdown list is not being selected.  I am building up an array of SelectListItems and setting the right one to selected = true but its not getting selected.

I have the following code in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var p = _myRepository.FindBy(id);
        var vm = new MyViewModel(p) { CategoryTypes = ControllerUtils.GetList(_myTypeRepository, r => r.Name, p.CategoryType.Id) };

        return View(vm);
    }
```

and here is the GetList function in the ControllerUtils class:

```
public static class ControllerUtils
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetList<T>(IIntKeyedRepository<T> list, Func<T, string> getName, int id) where T : BaseModel
    {
        var items = list.All().ToList();
        var itemsList = items.Select(r => new SelectListItem() { Selected = r.Id == id, Text = getName(r), Value = r.Id.ToString() });
        return itemsList;
    }
}
```

and here is my view code:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyObject.CategoryType)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyObject.CategoryType, Model.CategoryTypes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyObject.CategoryType)
    </div>
```

When i debug in the controller code and list into the array of SelectListItem objects i do see the second item has selected = true. But when i check the view HTML, I don't see either item being selected:

```
<select id="CategoryType" name="CategoryType">
  <option value="1">Choice 1</option>
  <option value="2">Choice 2</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, there is no "selected="selected" for either item.    Any suggestions on what could be going on here?

Comment: What's the value of `@Model.MyObject.CategoryType`? Do you have a corresponding item in `Model.CategoryTypes` with the same value?

Comment: CategoryType is an object with Id property (int) and Name property (string).  The Id property matches the CategoryTypes has Id and Text set to Name property of Categorytype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of the DropDownListFor helper must be a lambda expression pointing to a **primitive type** property on your view model containing the selected value:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.MyObject.CategoryType.Id, 
    Model.CategoryTypes
)
```

Now get rid of the `Selected = r.Id == id` property inside your `SelectListItem`. You don't need it. Now assuming that `Model.MyObject.CategoryType.Id` has a corresponding item with matching value inside `Model.CategoryTypes` the helper will automatically preselect this item.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `SelectListItem.Selected` property to tell which item is selected. I noticed that `DropDownListFor` ignores this.

Instead, you should have `model.MyObject.CategoryType` set to the value `2` (or `"2"`) in order for the dropdown to have the second item selected.

Comment: @wOlf - to clarify, model.MyObject.CategoryType is an object whose Id property is 2